# How To Roll My Own Set in Ancient Python/Jython?

Tags: python, jython, wlst, jython-2.2

Geeks/Nerds/Fellow Pythonists lend me your ears!

I wrote a script in Python 2.7 that uses the set() function. This is a built in data structure for only storing unique values. However I am running the script in a different environment. I know I should of coded in the same environment as the production environment. So in the production environment there is an ancient version of python running. From what I understand this is Python 2.2. Also, this Python interpreter is running on a Java Virtual Machine (JVM) which makes this Jython. Very cool. :) Anyway for whatever reason the set() data structure is not included in this version of Python. **Is there anyway I can create my own set using a list and then looking for only unique values?** This type of algorithm writing is currently over my head. Could someone point me in a helpful direction?

When running this code I see that the version is Python 2.2.

```
import sys
print sys.version_info
```

This code returns: `(2, 2, 1, 'final', 0)`

My code that throws the error is:

```
machine_set = set() #create a set, an empty set at that
```

The error I receive is as follows:

```
<me@linuxbox ~>$ java -cp $WEBLOGIC weblogic.WLST lolcats.py

Initializing WebLogic Scripting Tool (WLST) ...

Welcome to WebLogic Server Administration Scripting Shell

Type help() for help on available commands

Problem invoking WLST - Traceback (innermost last):
  File "/home/oracle/lolcats.py", line 18, in ?
TypeError: set() takes at least 2 arguments (0 given)
```

Comment: I hope you've got a migration path off of this ancient Jython.

Comment: Use a dictionary instead. Set items become keys and values are all `None`.

Comment: Dictionary keys are basically a set. Could you just create a dictionary with blank values and use membership tests? What do you need the set to do?

Comment: The [`sets`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) library from [Python 2.3-2.7](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.3/Lib/sets.py) is in pure Python, and should be compatible with 2.2, so you can just copy and paste it into your own project.

Comment: @abarnert: As long as you respect the license.

Comment: @abarnet Interesting. I may try this if nothing else works. I would just add my code at the bottom of this `sets` code or call this code as a module if I can get fancy in WLST/Jython. Thank-you for the cool idea.

Comment: @superbeck sets give you unique values. This is very helpful in certain situations.

Comment: @user2357112 It's pretty easy to respect the license for any versions but 1.6 and 2.1, but yeah, worth pointing out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you may not be stuck on Jython 2.2. It looks like 2.2.1 is what comes with your WLST, but Google suggests that [you may be able to use WLST with Jython 2.7](https://technology.amis.nl/2015/10/04/how-to-use-wlst-as-a-jython-2-7-module/). If you can use 2.7, that's likely to be a much nicer environment than 2.2. (It's still pretty dated by non-Jython standards, but it beats the heck out of 2.2.)

---

If that's not viable, still, don't use a list. Back when `set` didn't exist, the way to do sets was with a `dict` you'd ignore the values of. Same time complexity as a `set`, unlike what you'd get if you tried to use `list` for the job. The old [`sets`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) module that came before the built-in `set` type was actually implemented as a wrapper around dicts, and if you were on 2.3, I'd recommend `sets.Set`, but you're on 2.2.

```
# Add a value
d[val] = None

# Remove a value
del d[val]

# Check if a value exists (good thing it's not 2.1, or you'd need has_key)
key in d
```

Comment: Thanks for the details (code examples) in the answer. I will try using a dictionary. Also, thanks for pointing out the article on WLST and Jython 2.7. I will have to see if I can get this update. :)

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using a dict's keys for your set. Just set the values to something lightweight, like `1`.

Comment: Thank-you @gilch for the recommendation. I will try this. :)

Answer (score 1):

Python 2.3-2.7 have a [`sets`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) module (which is deprecated in 2.6+, because the new builtins `set` and `frozenset` do the same thing but better).

You don't have this in 2.2, but the module is implemented in pure Python. So—assuming you respect the [Python license](https://docs.python.org/3/license.html)—you can just [copy it from the 2.3 source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.3/Lib/sets.py) into your project. In fact, I have some code in an ancient project that starts with this:

```
try:
    set
except NameError:
    try:
        from sets import Set as set
    except ImportError:
        from sets23 import Set as set
```

… which implies that just copying 2.3's `sets.py` into your project as `sets23.py` works for 2.2. But I don't have a 2.2 to test on, so… I won't *promise* that it works without any porting, but I *think* it does.

---

Alternatively, those historical pre-2.3 set classes mentioned in the `sets` docs are still available in the [ActiveState recipes collection](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/langs/python/tags/set/). Not everything has been [migrated to the GitHub repo](https://github.com/ActiveState/code/tree/master/recipes/Python) (or, if it has, the new search isn't complete), but I can see [`106469_Yet_another_Set_class_for_Python`](https://github.com/ActiveState/code/tree/master/recipes/Python/106469_Yet_another_Set_class_for_Python), which is a minor fork of the original Greg Wilson implementation that `sets` is also a fork of.

Comment: Awesome. I may try this. :D